# Restoring SQL Server 2008 R2 *.bak databases on SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore, sql-server-2014-express

I recently changed my SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.1600.1) to SQL Server 2014 Express (12.0.4100.1 - with service pack 1). Now I would like to restore `*.bak` files that I have created on SQL Server 2008 R2.

First of all I can't see my `*.bak` files in the `Backup` directory (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.RALTECH\MSSQL\Backup`). I copied all my backup files there.

[image]

When I try to type backup file location at a push like this (one of my backup file is called RMP) I can see that Management Studio recognize the file :

[image]

[image]

The file (backup) size is 2201 KB and the database file is 2245632 (Size column in Management Studio - I don't know what unit is it MB or KB ...) However it's not bigger then acceptable size in SQL Server Express edition. So that's not the problem.

When I click ok to restore I get this error :

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore of database 'RMP' failed. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The operating system returned the error '5(Access denied.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.RALTECHSQL\MSSQL\DATA\RMP.mdf'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

What I can do with this ? How can I restore my databases on SQL Server 2014 Express from SQL Server 2008 R2 `*.bak` files ? What is strange for me my backup files (`*.bak`) have padlock icon. Could that be a problem ?

Thanks

Comment: All accounts in my system have "full control" privilage to that file as well to the whole directory. What can i do more with this ?

Comment: Check the permissions of the bak files. They are normally geared towards the Windows user running the database server that created the backup and not the user account that initiated the backup in SSMS. I remember in similar situation I just granted full access to Everyone on the backup dir, but this is far from best practice.

Comment: I think I've done it properly - I added 2 accounts with full permissions to this file (SamSs and MSSQL$RALTECH - RALTECH is my instance name). It didn't help. Did I do it wrong then ?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not permissions on the backup folder, it's the folder you're trying to get SQL server to create the new database files in.

As you backed it up from the old instance, SQL Server will default to trying to put the database files back into the folder they were originally in (In this case C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.RALTECHSQL\MSSQL\DATA)

You don't want this to happen because your new 2014 server doesn't have permissions to create files in this folder (plus they probably already exist, unless you deleted the DBs from the old instance), what you need to do is choose a new location for the files, so before you click restore, click on the files section of the restore dialog and choose a new location for the files, based on your folders shown it should be something like C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.RALTECH\MSSQL\DATA\

Your 2014 instance will have permissions to create files in here and the restore should work.